# In column G, If two consecutive blank rows are followed by a cell with characters, paste the set of characters into sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA (I've written two small scripts) so forgive me being new. I have tried this one out on my own for enough time now and seem to be going in circles. Any guidance or direction would be appreciated.

In column G (far right) in ascending order, If two or more consecutive blank rows are followed by any name within 1minute or less then copy that name and paste it in sheet 2. For the data below, Mike and Scott would be copied into sheet two.

```
13-11-04 6:36   10937   Service Identify Fail       0   
13-11-04 6:36   10937   Service Identify Fail       0   
13-11-04 6:37   10937   Service Identify Fail       0   
13-11-04 6:37   10937   Service Identify Success    In  28  Mike
13-11-04 6:59   10920   Reception Identify Success  In  280 Mandy
13-11-04 6:59   10937   Service Identify Success    In  210 Brian
13-11-04 7:03   10937   Service Identify Fail       0   
13-11-04 7:03   10937   Service Identify Fail       0   
13-11-04 7:03   10937   Service Identify Success    In  114 Scott
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are having trouble with

Comment: Does Within a minute mean with the values of column B showing the same time?

Comment: @sancho.s yes, the time column is actually part of the date column too (A), and it has seconds in the cell itself, they just do not show here. I would like to set the threshold of 30 seconds difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I am not quite sure about is how to check if it has been within a minute of each other, but this is the code that I have so far.

```
Private Sub printName()
    Dim nameRange, c3ll As Range
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastr0w = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    Set nameRange = ws1.Range("G1:G" & lastr0w)

    For Each c3ll In nameRange
        'can't be the 1st two cells since there needs to be 2 or more consecutive black rows previous to selected cell
        If c3ll.Row > 2 And c3ll.Value <> Empty Then
            prev1 = ws1.Cells(c3ll.Row - 1, 7).Value
            prev2 = ws1.Cells(c3ll.Row - 2, 7).Value
            If IsEmpty(prev1) And IsEmpty(prev2) Then
                ws2.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
                For i = 2 To 7
                    ws2.Cells(1, i) = ws1.Cells(c3ll.Row, i)
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    Next c3ll
End Sub
```

PS I am new to VBA as well, but I am using these questions as a way to learn and teach myself code.

Comment: This is a great help @hessr17! I am working on the time difference now